# Show multiline text in grails page

Tags: string, grails, newline, gsp

I'm going mad with this, I need to show a text I got from a textarea in grails 2.3.7 but when I replace \r\n characters for br/ and do an encodeAsHTML() I get the br's every where instead of new lines.

How is it done? this is what I've tried:

```
${cotizacionInstance.descripcion.encodeAsHTML().replaceAll('\r\n', '<br/>')}

${cotizacionInstance.descripcion.replaceAll('\r\n', '<br/>').encodeAsHTML()}

<%=cotizacionInstance.descripcion.replaceAll('\r\n', '<br/>').encodeAsHTML()%>

<%=cotizacionInstance.descripcion.encodeAsHTML().replaceAll('\r\n', '<br/>')%>

<%=cotizacionInstance.descripcion.replaceAll('\r\n', '<br/>').decodeHTML()%>

<%=cotizacionInstance.descripcion.decodeHTML().replaceAll('\r\n', '<br/>')%>
```

I don't like the way it comes out if I use the pre tag, because I loose all responsiveness.

I see that in the google chrome inspector I get my string between double quotes but I don't know how to remove those.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are factors left out of your description which make it impossible to say for sure but one way to get the behavior you are after is to mark the text as raw with something like this...

```
${raw(cotizacionInstance.descripcion.replaceAll('\r\n', '<br/>'))}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: More info about that can be found at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/security.html#xssPrevention.

Comment: Make sure you understand how all of that works.  If the value of `cotizacionInstance.descripcion` might contain malicious markup and you mark it as raw, whatever is in that value will be rendered unescaped.  Depending on your app, maybe that is ok, but it is something to be cautious about.

Comment: This is what I needed thanks!, I will use encodeAsHTML before the replace so malicious markup won't harm me ;)

Comment: Just for posterity: the correct solution looks like this:
`${raw(cotizacionInstance.descripcion.encodeAsHTML()).replaceAll("\\n", "<br/>"}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to esacpe your backslashes:

```
replaceAll("\\n", "<br/>")
```

Comment: the replaceAll is working the problem is that I see the <br/> instead of getting a new line

Comment: That would only make sense if she is trying to replace the literal backslash followed by an n.  I don't think that is what she is trying to do.  I think she is trying to replace newline characters.